# The meaning of "tend to be better"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was reading a book when i faced the sentence below.

> Our national representatives tend to be better than our local ones.

What's the meaning of "tend to be better" in this sentence?

Note 1: I get the main point of it, The local representatives (e.g. local politicians) are weaker than the national ones.
But I want to translate this sentence, And the problem is that i don't find a suitable synonym for "tend to be better".

Note 2: There is a similar question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111841/tend-to-be-become-tending). But the explanations the users gave are not enough for me to understand and do the translation.

Comment: What's wrong with the explanation linked in the related question? http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tend Specifically, this is an example of the first definition, 1a. It basically means, "national representatives are usually better (more skilled/experienced/...) than local ones".

Comment: The word **usually** begs the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To tend" is the intransitive verb form of the noun "tendency":

> [**tendency**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tendency) (n): *a likelihood to happen or to have a particular characteristic or effect:*

Examples:

> She has a tendency to work late -> She **tends to** work late.
>
> I have a tendency to hum when I'm thinking -> I **tend to** hum when I'm thinking.

In your example, "X tends to be better than Y" means that X *is likely to be* or *is more often* better than Y.  You can use this structure in a variety of ways:

> She **tends to wake up earlier** than her sister.
>
> I **tend to be more meticulous** than my coworkers.
>
> They **tend to be taller** than the average for that region.